# Serving angular SPA and another index.html from nginx

Tags: angularjs, nginx, nginx-location

I have a SPA and serving it from Nginx which works fine. I also have an simple index.html inside a sub-folder.

Spa links to index.html for displaying a sub application which is simple html with it's own css/js. When trying to browse the subfolder app, nginx redirects to the base spa.

nginx config

```
 location / {              
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }

location /3d-viewer/ {
                 try_files $uri $uri/ /3d-viewer/index.html;
        }
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you tried just swapping those rules - moving the `/3d-viewer/` before the "capture all"? Supposedly if it matches the first rule, it will not hit the secon one.

Comment: Yes, I have. It didn't work.

Comment: Resolved, Gulp task was merging the index.html with the SPAs index.html and resulting in a 404.

Comment: So your nginx config was correct all along?

Comment: Yes!!! duh me  :)

Comment: Haha. Good catch with the gulp process!

Comment: I just want to add that Nginx matches the longest location path.

Answer (score 0):

in angular app config https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/3d-viewer'}]
})
class AppModule {}
```

nginx.conf

```
location /3d-viewer {
  alias /var/www/html/3d-viewer;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  expires 0;
  add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
  add_header X-Cache-Status REVALIDATED;
  break;
}
```